# Can Connect to Database via Command Line but not in Python Script?

Tags: python, mysql, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

I hope the title is pretty self explanatory. I set up a database and web-server on the same machine using Amazon RDS and EC2 instance. I am running a Python script in the machine's `cgi` folder, and am having trouble connecting to the database. The errors are on the order of: `_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2003, "Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1' (111)")`

I have tried this with `mySQLdb` and `_mysql` without success. What I can't understand is that I am able to successfully connect to the mysql client via the command line with `mysql -u username -p -h edutechfinal.cqk0lckbky4e.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com` but not inside the script.

This is what I have tried in the Python script

`db = _mysql.connect("127.0.0.1","st4rgut25","pwd","st4rgut25")`

and

`db = MySQLdb.connect(host="127.0.0.1",user="st4rgut25",passwd="pwd",db="st4rgut25")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The RDS instance is not running on the EC2 instance, they're separate "machines". From the EC2 instance, instead of using the loopback address `127.0.0.1`, which would assume MySQL is running on the local EC2 instance, just use the host name `edutechfinal.cqk0lckbky4e.us-east-2.rds.amazonaws.com` as you're doing from the MySQL client.